# Ideal computer for running Tails and Tor on Windows?

Tags: tails, windows

I read the system requirements for Tor and Tails, but for Windows-based x86 (64-bit) systems, what properties or hardware should someone steer away from when making a purchase that might make the system allergic to Tor and Tails? In other words, prevent them from working properly, given that systems cannot be returned once bought?

What sort of issues are known for running Tails and Tor on Windows systems? Are Intel Celeron, AMD or other processor too weak to run Tails and Tor?

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend you QubesOS instead of Tails, but the requirements are basically the same:

- At least a dual-core chip with **true** two cores, i.e. don't forget about Intel HyperThreading's virtual cores
- At least 8Gb of RAM. Yes, 8 - and not 4 or smaller, because you need some RAM for your regular tasks to run smoothly
- 256Gb **fast** SSD - so disk will not ruin your day. If you have an option to choose either a 256 fast one or 512 of slow/green/regular one - choose the fast one!
- a discrete video card. Yes, Intel's built-in/integrated ones can do the job, but they are slow and are often ruining the GUI experience because of the fact that many graphical tasks are perfectly accelerated by the discrete video cards, especially by NVidia ones or a beefy Radeon/Radeon Vega. Yes, Vega is supposed to be counted as a built-in one, but as my experience is showing me - it fits the task. But NVidia is preferred

P.S. Just forgot to mention: ARM is good too and keep in mind that ALL of the ARM video cores are counted as discrete because of SoC paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

Tails is based on Debian so the hardware support is basically the same.

You should definitively have a look at [the known issues](https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/index.en.html), which lists the problematic hardware.

From my experience, Lenovo Thinkpads are perfectly supported.